# Is there a way to control assistive touch in application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want the assistive touch to automatically slide to Left side of my iPhone when open my application and the app detects that assistive touch is not on the Left side.

So any way to acheive this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot control the assistive touch because Apple has not provided any official APIs for that. I tried googling about it, But I didn't found any relevant link regarding controlling the Assistive Touch.